# In which software I can draw these customized mathematical figures?

Tags: geometry, math-software

I'm digitizing my math notes, and I'm looking for a suitable software to draw mainly these 4 figures accurately. I've used GeoGebra, but in some cases I'm unable to draw the figure perfectly, for example, the spiral in image 2.

[image: Complex Principle Argument]
[image: Spiral]
[image: Length of Modulus with bidirectional arrow]
[image: n-th root of Complex Number]

Can you please suggest any software/book to draw these figures?

Comment: software/**book**? How is a book supposed to help you draw diagrams better?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, for example, a software like manim, where I can code to draw diagrams.

Comment: Are you familiar with LaTex? If so, then browse for TikZ package - probably the most complex and powerful tool to create graphic elements in LaTeX.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak thank you for suggesting the package. Let me try. Btw, I'm new in LaTeX.

Comment: [asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) produces nice pictures (with some work).

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondManzoni

Comment: TikZ, Asymptote, LaTeXdraw, Xfig... You can also do your figures with R and convert them to TikZ.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent with R? :O Can you please suggest any link for that? I've no idea about it.

Comment: If you are a LaTeX user, have a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing

Comment: Thank you @Cesareo

Comment: @DebtanuGupta You can do an ordinary graphic with R and there is a package to convert it to TikZ code (tikZdevice package). Very easy if you know R.

Comment: OK ok! Thanks @StéphaneLaurent